# Ubuntu freezes when RAM usage spikes

Tags: 20.04, firefox, freeze, ram, gimp

This issue persisted for a while, but it feels like it became extremely frequent (instead of once in a while, it happens almost every day) once I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.

Whenever stuff happens - it seems to me like it's when RAM usage gets high (I've seen people describe similar problem with disk I/O, but this doesn't appear to be the case) - the system borderline freezes. For a first minute, the system will just drastically chug, and I have a short window of opportunity to move the now jittery mouse cursor to quickly close the browser tab or application that is causing the issue. If I don't do that, at this point the system pretty much freezes permanently, system clock on the top bar stops updating, and it won't unfreeze no matter what happens, and I need to do a hard reset.

Previously, this happened often on Firefox when I had too many tabs open, but I installed a tab limiter extension to mitigate this. But it just keeps happening, it happens (sometimes) when I'm working on a bigger image in GIMP, and when I browse some sites with infinite scrolling, like DeviantArt redesign or some video sites. I just lost half an hour of progress on a pixel art piece I was working on in GIMP.

This is rendering my system really annoying to use. I hate to say it, but Windows 10 I have in dual boot is more stable - and that's saying something, since W10 is the worst operating system I ever used.

Here is an inxi -F dump:

```
System:
  Host: shino-ProLiant-ML310-G5p Kernel: 5.4.0-66-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: HP product: ProLiant ML310 G5p v: N/A 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: N/A model: N/A serial: N/A BIOS: HP v: W08 date: 10/25/2010 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Xeon E3120 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
  Speed: 1995 MHz min/max: N/A Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1995 2: 1995 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD ES1000 driver: N/A 
  Device-2: NVIDIA G86 [Quadro NVS 290] driver: nvidia v: 340.108 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1440x900~75Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Quadro NVS 290/PCIe/SSE2 v: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.108 
Audio:
  Device-1: Generalplus type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-66-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5715 Gigabit Ethernet 
  driver: tg3 
  IF: enp3s4f0 state: down mac: 9c:8e:99:35:15:80 
  Device-2: Broadcom and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5715 Gigabit Ethernet 
  driver: tg3 
  IF: enp3s4f1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full 
  mac: 9c:8e:99:35:15:81 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 594.46 GiB (31.9%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda model: LOGICAL VOLUME size: 1.82 TiB 
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Hewlett-Packard Smart Array G6 controllers driver: hpsa 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 910.88 GiB used: 594.46 GiB (65.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 40.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 68 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 288 Uptime: 2h 17m Memory: 3.84 GiB used: 2.86 GiB (74.6%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Have you booted from live media and run memtest?

Comment: What is your `vm.swappiness` set for in your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file?

Comment: @Terrance There is no vm.swappiness in that file. In fact, entire file is commented out.

Comment: You can try using that setting to see if that helps.  The higher the number the more aggressive towards using the swap it is.  The lower, the less.  You can try using it with `echo "vm.swappiness = 10" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf` then run `sudo sysctl -p` to activate it.  I am thinking that your system might be swapping RAM too early thus causing the "hang ups".

Comment: `vm.swappiness` is not necessarily about RAM actual usage but more about the pages getting swapped in and out.  A descent explanation about it can be found here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging#Swappiness  You can try playing with the numbers, but I have noticed my system actually running better with a number like 10.  I believe that Ubuntu defaults to 60.

Comment: @Terrance Okay, I tried that. If it will work, I will comment here so you can write this as an answer.

Comment: @Terrance Okay, I did it. I just tried opening like ten tabs, and at the same time opening a large image in GIMP, and scrolling several pages down in my favs on Deviantart - previously any single one of these could've caused the freeze. It seems I'm cured. To be sure, I will wait 2 days -  if it doesn't freeze once by then, on second March I will @ you again, so you can copy your comment into an answer, and I will accept it. Huge thanks!

Comment: @Terrance You can add an answer and I will accept, it worked! Several days with no freezes. I can't thank you enough, this was making my Ubuntu unusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging#Swappiness it states:

> Swappiness is a Linux kernel parameter that controls the relative weight given to swapping out of runtime memory, as opposed to dropping pages from the system page cache, whenever a memory allocation request cannot be met from free memory. Swappiness can be set to values between 0 and 200 (inclusive).[18] A low value causes the kernel to prefer to evict pages from the page cache while a higher value causes the kernel to prefer to swap out "cold" memory pages. The default value is 60; setting it higher can cause high latency if cold pages need to be swapped back in (when interacting with a program that had been idle for example), while setting it lower (even 0) may cause high latency when files that had been evicted from the cache need to be read again, but more responsive programs. Swapping can also slow down HDDs further because it involves a lot of random writes, while SSDs do not have this problem. Certainly the default values work well in most workloads, but desktops and interactive systems for any expected task may want to lower the setting while batch processing and less interactive systems may want to increase it.[19]

Since Ubuntu defaults to a `vm.swappiness` value of `60`, I recommend a lower value, i.e. `10`, so that the inactive pages in RAM are less aggressive towards the swap.

Run the following to set a value of `10` (*if no value is set in the .conf file yet*):

```
echo "vm.swappiness = 10" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

If the setting already exists, you can copy and paste the following to change the value to `10`:

```
sudo sed -i "s/$(awk '/vm.swappiness/ {print $0}' /etc/sysctl.conf)/vm.swappiness\ =\ 10/" /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Then activate the changes:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

You can also try different values to see what may work best for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oops, I forgot to accept this. Thanks for your patience, and for your help, once again.

Comment: I didn't see any discussion about how much RAM or swap OP had, so how did you determine that vm.swappiness=10 was appropriate?

Comment: @heynnema It was actually a guess based on slowness of the system running.  I have actually been doing more research into the `vm.swappiness` settings and how they are used.  However, I have not written an answer on it yet.  https://askubuntu.com/q/1324625/231142 has a comment from me about the swappiness itself.   I have done tests on that comment to confirm it.

Comment: Articles that blindly recommend vm.swappiness=10 are mostly rubbish, and many users that I help have blindly set theirs to 10 and then wondered why the system isn't running correctly. vm.swappiness (by itself) should be adjusted based on a number of factors, including RAM size, swap or /swapfile size/usage, and what apps are normally running and how the system is utilized.

Comment: @heynnema But, vm.swappiness has zero effect on the actual usage of the swap itself.  vm.swappiness=0 does not disable swap one single bit.  The article is not blindly recommending it but giving you examples.  The unfortunate part is that it doesn't specify what sufficient RAM is.  8GB could be sufficient, 16GB or 32GB+.  It all has to deal with what you need it for.  vm.swappiness has to deal with inactive tasks in RAM and how they are swapped out.  vm.swappiness=100 will swap the tasks as soon as they go inactive thus making the system seem to hang.

Comment: @Terrance A couple of inaccuracies in your comment. *"vm.swappiness has zero effect on the actual usage of the swap"* is blatantly incorrect, and *"vm.swappiness has to deal with inactive tasks in RAM"* it actually has nothing to do with inactive **tasks** in RAM, but with "least recently used **pages** of memory".

Comment: @heynnema But, I am running my system with vm.swappiness=0 on 24GB of RAM without any issues or hangups.  I am also not running anything that needs to be swapped out of RAM because of it going inactive.  And yes, I can still hibernate my system without any issues.  I think you need to study more into vm.swappiness please.

Comment: @Terrance Load up a lot of memory intensive apps... Chrome with a ton of open tabs... or a VS Code with large open files... and watch `free -h` for what happens to RAM and swap and when your system might start to misbehave with high RAM/swap usage. *"I am also not running anything that needs to be swapped out into RAM"* unless you're manually writing optimized code, you have no direct control of what gets "swapped out into RAM"... and it doesn't really "swap out to RAM" anyway... **pages** of RAM get swapped into/out of a swap partition or /swapfile.

Comment: @heynnema I am really not in the mood for this today. Please don't act like you know everything.  What works for me may not work for others and vice versa. This answer worked fine for the OP.  Enough said!

Comment: @Terrance Fair enough. However... I never "act"... giggle.